# How to get city code weather in AccuWeather?

Tags: weather

Have someone ever use AccuWeather to search your country weather? I want to get my city weather code in AccuWeather who can help me? The code generate has form like this: EUR|DE|GM014|TORGAU. I can't find my city code (Phnom Penh, Cambodia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Phnom Penh, the code you seek is ASI|KH|CB012|PHNOM PENH.

Now in general, getting that old style format is difficult because around the end of 2009 / beginning of 2010 they did away with that style of coding stations and replaced it with a newer, perhaps more friendly model.  So new style,

http://www.accuweather.com/en/kh/phnom-penh/49785/weather-forecast/49785

will give you the current for Phnom Penh.

If you really really really need to find the old style codes, there is an awesome list [here](http://pastebin.com/dbtemx5F).  I would recommend you download the list from here as it is gold at this point and then you can programmatically access it however you see fit.  Regex would be a good bet as the format seems to be pretty consistent.

Answer (score 6):

to find your location
use this link provided by the help in ubuntu

http://thale.accu-weather.com/widget/thale/city-find.asp?location=

add your location at the end of the link

*http://thale.accu-weather.com/widget/thale/city-find.asp?location=PARIS*

Comment: Does not work anymore :-/
"Your subscription has expired. Please contact AccuWeather to resubscribe"

Answer (score 2):

Find your (nearest) city here: http://pastebin.com/dbtemx5F

Comment: Thanks, Nick! That did the job!